$f$ is a support functional for $\bar{U}(0,\Vert a \Vert)$ at $a$ iff $\Vert f\Vert \Vert a\Vert=f(a)$.
The exercise is given:

Let $0\neq a\in X$ and $0\neq f\in X'$. Then $f$ is a support functional for $\bar{U}(0,\Vert a \Vert)$ at $a$ iff $\Vert f\Vert \Vert a\Vert=f(a)$.

For the forward direction, assuming $f$, a support functional for $\bar{U}(0,\vert a \Vert)$ at $a$, we already have $f(a)\le|f(a)|\le\Vert f \Vert \Vert a \Vert.$ Again, from the definition of support functional, we have $Ref(x)\le Ref(a)$ where $x\in X$ with $\Vert x\Vert\le\Vert a \Vert.$ Then, how to reach $\Vert f \Vert \Vert a \Vert \le f(a)$?

Fix $x_0 \in X$ with $\|x_0\| \le\|a\|$. Since $Re f(x) \le Re f(a)$ on $\overline U(0,\|a\|)$ you get in case $f(x_0) \not=0$ that
$$
\frac{\overline{f(x_0)}}{|f(x_0)|} x_0 \in \overline U(0,\|a\|), ~ \text{hence} ~ |f(x_0)| \le Re f(a),
$$
which trivially also holds in case $f(x_0) =0$. Thus
$$
\forall x \in \overline U(0,\|a\|): ~ |f(x)| \le Re f(a).
$$
Application to $x=a$ yields $|f(a)| \le Re f(a)$, so $f(a)$ is real and $\ge 0$. So we have $|f(x)| \le f(a)$ on $\overline U(0,\|a\|)$, that is
$|f(x)| \le f(a)/\|a\|$ on $\overline U(0,1)$, and taking the supremum on the left hand side shows $\|f\| \le f(a)/\|a\|$.

Thank you so much!!!
